# How to index blob content with existing "content" field that is Collection(Edm.String)?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I can successfully index documents like PDFs, etc... from blob storage with Azure Search and it will go into a field by default called `content`.

But what I want to achieve is:

- index the blob file content to a field called `fileContent` (`Edm.String`)
- have a field for other uses called `content` (`Collection(Edm.String)`)

And I cannot make this work without an error. I've tried everything with some success but from what I can tell it's not possible to redirect the data to a different field other than `content` while also having a `content` field defined that is `Collection(Edm.String)`.

Here's what I've tried:

Have output field mappings setup so that the content goes into a field called "fileContent". For example:

```json
  "outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/content",
      "targetFieldName": "fileContent"
    }
  ]
```

This works fine and the content of the file goes into the `fileContent` field defined as `Edm.String`. However, if I create add a custom field called `content` in my index defined as `Collection(Edm.String)` I get an exception during the indexing operation:

*The data field 'content' in the document with key '1234' has an invalid value of type 'Edm.String' (String maps to Edm.String). The expected type was 'Collection(Edm.String)'.*

Why does it care what my data type for `content` is when I'm mapping this to a different field?

I have verified that if I make the `content` field just `Edm.String` I don't get an error but now I have duplicate entries in the index since both `content` and `fileContent` contain the same information.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage) it's possible to change the field from `content` to something else (but then it doesn't tell you how):

> A content field is common to blob content. It contains the text extracted from blobs. Your definition of this field might look similar to the one above. You aren't required to use this name, but doing lets you take advantage of implicit field mappings. The blob indexer can send blob contents to a content Edm.String field in the index, with no field mappings required.

I've also tried using normal (non output) `fieldMappings` to redirect the input `content` field to `fileContent` but I end up with the same error if `content` is also defined with `Collection(Edm.String)`

```json
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "content",
      "targetFieldName": "fileContent",
      "mappingFunction": null
    }
```

I've also tried redirecting this content through a skillset but even though I can capture that output in a custom field, as soon as I add the `content` (`Collection(Edm.String)`) everything explodes.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

**Update** Turns out that the above (non output) fieldMapping does work so long as the `fileContent` type is just `Edm.String`. However, if you want to add a skillset to process this data, that data needs to be redirected to yet-another-field. It will not allow you to redirect that back to `fileContent` and you end up an error like: "*Target
Parameter name: Enrichment target name 'fileContent' collides with existing '/document/fileContent'*". So it seems that you end up being required to store the raw blob document data in a field and if you want to process it, it requires another field which is quite annoying.

Comment: Is the Collection(String) field "content" intended to be ignored by the indexer?

Comment: Yes that's the goal in this case. To be able to have Collection(String) field called "content" for custom data while also having the blob indexer push it's content to another field

Answer (score 1):

The indexer will try to index as much content as possible by matching index field names, that's why it attempts to put the blob `content` string into the index field `content` collection (and fails).

To get around this you need to add a (non output) field mapping from `content` to another name that's not an index field name, such as `blobContent` to prevent the indexer from being too eager. Then in the skillset you can use `blobContent` by either

1. replacing all occurrences of `/document/content` with `/document/blobContent`, or
2. setting a value for `/document/content` which is only accessible within the skillset (and output field mappings), with a [conditional skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-conditional#sample-skill-definition-4-data-transformation-on-a-single-field) to minimize other changes to your skillset

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.ConditionalSkill",
    "context": "/document",
    "inputs": [
        { "name": "condition", "source": "= true" },
        { "name": "whenTrue", "source": "/document/blobContent" },
        { "name": "whenFalse", "source": "= null" }
    ],
    "outputs": [ { "name": "output", "targetName": "content" } ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'll check that out!